# How should I interpret notation such as $(X \times I) / (X \times \{0\})$ when dealing with quotient spaces?

Tags: general-topology, notation

I am learning point set topology for the first time and have just encountered cones. I understand that, given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set $X$, the quotient space is defined as the set of equivalence classes, denoted by $X\:/\sim$, equipped with the quotient topology. I have just been introduced to the cone $CX$ of a topological space $X$. I understand that $CX$ is the quotient space of $X \times I$ given by the equivalence relation

$$
(x', 0) \sim (x, 0), \forall x \in X
$$

where $I$ is the closed unit interval in $\mathbb{R}$. The cone of a set $X$ is typically denoted by:

$$
CX = (X \times I)\:/\:(X \times \{0\}) 
$$

From the formal definition of a cone, I understand what this notation means. $CX$ is the quotient space given by the equivalence relation which maps all members of  $X \times \{0\}$ to the same equivalence class, and any other element of $X \times I$ to its own unique class.

Is this how I should generally expect this notation to be used? For example, if I were to see a quotient space defined as follows:

$$
X / A
$$

where $A$ is a subset of $X$ (rather than an equivalence relation on $X$), should I just take this quotient space to be the one which corresponds to the equivalence relation where all members of $A$ belong to the same class, and all other members of $X$ each belong to their own unique class?

Comment: You're right, see the *adjunction space* example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)).

Comment: Yes, that is the exact meaning of $X/A$. It is sort of a confusing notation because hidden here is an equivalence relation. A more descriptive notation would be $X/\sim$ where $x \sim y$ if and only if $x, y \in A$ (where $A$ is a subset of $X$).

Comment: It is also confusing because this has another entirely different meaning when X is a vector space and A is a subspace.

Comment: @Ruy yes, also in the case of groups and a subgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally I think of $X/A$ to mean all the points of $A$ are glued together as to be indistinguishable while the other elements of $X$ are left unchanged. This means the equivalence classes are all singletons except for $A$ which is its own equivalence class as you have correctly deduced.